# How many good/bad question votes required to qualify question as part of a proposal?

Tags: discussion, area-51, stackexchange-2.0

Curiosity is killing me.

When an Area 51 proposal is in the definition stage, it says so in the upper-right hand corner and says that to proceed, it needs X more followers, Y more on-topic questions, and Z more off-topic questions.

So how many votes is required for a question to be proposal-accepted?  The FAQ is mute on this issue.

Is it a concrete number of votes either way?  Or is it some formula that takes all the good/bad/meh votes into account?  Is there some sort of color coding applied to those accepted answers that I haven't noticed yet?

Or has the Stack Exchange team kept this a tightly guarded secret so they can change the criteria midstream?

Answer (score 2):

A question needs 20 on-topic or off-topic votes to be considered on-topic or off-topic.  This is documented somewhere but is eluding me right now.